# rfuzz compile error in ruby 1.9.2

Tags: c, ruby

I am trying to compile the c extension for rfuzz. The error i get is

```
make gcc -I. -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/i686-linux -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I/usr/local/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -fPIC -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-long-long  -o http11_client.o -c http11_client.c
http11_client.c: In function ‘client_http_field’:
http11_client.c:36:22: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11_client.c:36:50: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
http11_client.c: In function ‘HttpClientParser_execute’:
http11_client.c:218:23: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘ptr’
http11_client.c:219:23: error: ‘struct RString’ has no member named ‘len’
make: *** [http11_client.o] Error 1
```

RString is in Ruby.h. The struct in ruby.h does indeed have those members.

```
struct RString {
    struct RBasic basic;
    union {
        struct {
            long len;
            char *ptr;
            union {
                long capa;  
                VALUE shared;
            } aux;
        } heap;
        char ary[RSTRING_EMBED_LEN_MAX + 1];
    } as;
};
```

What am I missing?

Comment: +1 for mentioning an interesting gem.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like [RFuzz](http://rfuzz.rubyforge.org/) isn't compatible with Ruby 1.9.2. The `RString` definition for 1.9.2 is as you listed but for 1.8.7 it looks like this:

```
struct RString {
    struct RBasic basic;
    long len;
    char *ptr;
    union {
        long capa;
        VALUE shared;
    } aux;
};
```

which matches what the RFuzz source seems to be looking for. So you can either drop down to 1.8 for using RFuzz or you can try to port RFuzz to work with newer versions of Ruby.

The RFuzz website doesn't appear to have been updated since 2006 so it might not be maintained at all anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the ruby source code; just by looking at what you posted:

The type `struct RString` has 2 members: `basic` (of type `struct RBasic`) and `as` (of untagged union type).

The untagged union identified by `as` has 2 members: `heap` of untagged struct type and `ary` of array of char type.

The untagged struct identified by `heap` has the `ptr` member.

So to reach it you need

```
struct RString x;
x.as.heap.ptr; /* this is a char* */
```